# How to remove double quotes in csv file with Python

Tags: python, csv

I've managed to split a row of numbers separated by commas into new columns with each number in a row. However,i am not sure how to remove the double quote from the start and end of each row.

This is my code :

```
import csv
from csv import writer


COLUMNS = 6

with open("Winning No - Sheet1.csv", "r") as input:
    with open("output_file.csv", "w") as f:
        output = writer(f, delimiter=";")
        output.writerow(["Col {}".format(i+1) for i in xrange(COLUMNS)])
        for row in input:
            output.writerow(row.split(','))
```

Output that i get:

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 COL5 COL6 
"22    23   25   32   33   36"
```

p/s: Need to remove the double quotes from col1 and col6.

I edited my code into, but i still didn't get the output that i wanted :

```
output = writer(f, delimiter=";", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, doublequote=False, escapechar=' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `.strip()` method, which you call on a string, and which takes a single argument - the string sequence you want to remove from the left and right sides of a string. E.g.

```
s = '$$cat$$'
s.strip('$') # results in 'cat'
```

Your example:

```
import csv
from csv import writer

COLUMNS = 6

with open("Winning No - Sheet1.csv", "r") as input:
    with open("output_file.csv", "w") as f:
        output = writer(f, delimiter=";")
        output.writerow(["Col {}".format(i+1) for i in xrange(COLUMNS)])
        for row in input:
            output.writerow(row.strip('"').split(','))
```

Comment: The double quote was removed from the first column but not the last one.                        Output that i get:

    COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 COL5 COL6 
    22    23   25   32   33   36"

Comment: Try `output.writerow(row.lstrip('"').row.rstrip('"').split(','))`

Comment: @Kirthana Govindarajaoo that means you actually have a character after your last ", possibly a space.

Comment: @duhaime Plus one for the answer. Any suggestions on how to handle the space scenario. I tried to reproduce the problem with the test data and space got converted to the double double quotes. 1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;"
"

1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;11;"
"

Comment: @CppLearner, if *all* double quotes should be removed, one can just do `mystring.replace(string_to_replace, replacement_value)` -- then we can specify the string to replace as `'"'` (a double quote, wrapped in single quotes), and we indicate we want to replace the double quote with nothing: `mystring.replace('"', '')`. Otheriwse, to use the strip method when there are trailing spaces one can do `mystring.strip().strip('"')`. The first strip `mystring.strip()` removes all leading and trailing whitespace (like javascript's `.trim()`), and the latter removes leading/trailing double quotes...

Comment: @duhaime, Upvoted your comment. Thank you for your explanation and time.

Comment: @CppLearner thanks very much for asking good questions--have fun with Python!

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me :

```
output.writerow(row.replace('\"','').split(','))
```

Thank you so much for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

use this for the output.

```
var str="test"
str.replace(/^"|"$/g, '')
```